# IIS redirect rules to multiple 500 error page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, response.redirect, http-status-code-500

I need to return a different static page, for the 500 response type, depending on the language particle of the request (fr, es, pt, etc)

Is it possible to have one static page for each language (500-fr.aspx, 500-es.aspx, 500-pt.aspx) and somehow, depending on the language particle to return the necesary static page?

Eg:  mysite.com/fr/somepage is broken and returns a 500 response, and then IIS redirects the user to 500-fr.aspx page.

Thank you

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1201285.aspx?Problem+with+language+specific+error+pages Natively supported by Windows/IIS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple and fast way, that does not even require you to manually write url rewriting rules.

In the Error Pages module, IIS has defined the same error to display different pages according to different languages.

[image]

You can see that it has checked "Try to return the error file in the client languag". And if you enter the file path.

[image]

Error pages of different languages already exist in different language folders.

So if you want to response custom page, just change these pages or create new error pages store into different folder and change the file name in file path.
[image]